# How to draw CvConnectedComp in OpenFrameworks

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks

OpenCv's cvCamShift outputs a CvConnectedComp object which contains a contour property. I assume this is the contour represents the outline of my tracked object.

How do I draw this contour on the screen in OpenFrameworks?

Comment: hey, what about your previous question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528325/how-to-draw-square-with-hsv-color-in-openframeworks-opencv

Comment: Yup, that is my question. What do you want to know about it?

Comment: Why don't you solve problems in order?

Comment: The two questions are unrelated. Knowing how to convert between HSV and RGB doesn't have much bearing on this question

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the handy and nice add ons [ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv). This add ons easily get you all the function to convert opencv data structures into open frameworks ones and viceversa.

There are various example that show how to deal with contours, and with this add ons you can use the opencv C++ API, that are the new standard to deal with OpenCV.

Don't be afraid to ask again in the comments if you have some problems.